# How to set index for model attributes in Sails js?

Tags: sails.js

Here's my model class：

```js
module.exports =
{
  attributes:
  {
    id          : {type: 'integer', unique: true, primaryKey: true},
    title       : {type:'string', required:true},
    firstName   : {type:'string', required:true},
    lastName    : {type:'string', required:true},
    phone       : {type:'string', required:true},
    email       : {type:'string', required:true, unique: true},
    password    : {type:'string', required:false},
    roles       : {type:'array'}
  }
}
```

How to set index for the email and phone attributes?
Also, is it possible to create compule index like index(firstName,lastName)?

I tried hard to search on Google but did not find any result about creating an index in model class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an index property to any attribute to create an index **if your adapter supports it**. You specify an **index** attribute.

Currently Waterline doesn't support multi-column indexes in the attributes definition.

Also, when adding a **unique** property to an attribute, an index will automatically be created for that attribute.

In your example, we just need to add **index: true**, to the **phone** attribute.

module.exports =

```
{
  attributes:
  {
    id          : {type: 'integer', unique: true, primaryKey: true},
    title       : {type:'string', required:true},
    firstName   : {type:'string', required:true},
    lastName    : {type:'string', required:true},
    phone       : {type:'string', required:true, index: true},
    email       : {type:'string', required:true, unique: true},
    password    : {type:'string', required:false},
    roles       : {type:'array'}
  }
}
```

Although you are using Sailsjs, this is actually in the documentation for the Sails ORM which is Waterline - see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline).

Comment: Waterline doesn't support multi-column indexing or indexing of string fields. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline#indexing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline#indexing)

Comment: @m.spyratos, this link you posted seems to have been modified and does not contain the #indexing reference you mentioned, however, this might be a suitable replacement: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1354